# Permission denied while calling json from c# class

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to call `json` from `c#` class library and below is the code I am using. While accessing the `json` url in browser, I am able to see the respective data. But from code it is giving **You dont have permission to call this URL**

Please help how to overcome this error.

**Program**:

URL:

string url= https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-tip/jsonrpc.cgi?method=Product.get&params=[{"ids":"4"}]

```
try
{
    string ret = string.Empty;
    StreamWriter requestWriter;
    var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    if (webRequest != null)
    {
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        webRequest.Timeout = 20000;

        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        //POST the data.
        using (requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            requestWriter.Write(postData);
        }
    }
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
    ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return ret;
}
catch (WebException exception)
{
    string responseText;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(exception.Response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a "GET" not a POST right?

Change this:

```
webRequest.Method = "POST";
```

to

```
webRequest.Method = "GET";
```

Comment: when i change this to get I am getting execption like "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."

Comment: Removed the post data section and its working fine now :) thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I pass parameter in Json?